# Issue when open/save excel files with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to access excel modules with C# and I am having trouble after saving the excel file.

There are duplicate Thisworkbook and Sheets appearing as the picture below.

This only happens when the excel file has Modules while everything will be fine if the excel has only sheets in the project.

Here is the code which is nothing but only opening and saving the same file.

I am using WIN10/ VS2013 /EXCEL 2010.

Does anyone know why will this happen?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filepath = @"C:\test.xls";
        Excel._Application app = new Excel.Application();
        Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(filepath);


        workbook.SaveAs(filepath);

        workbook.Close(true);


        app.Quit();

    }
}
```

}

[image: Snapshot of the project list after saving the excel file]

Comment: What happens if you manually create a new spreadsheet in Excel?

Comment: take a look at the following article, might help you out https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/72c373b1-9f9b-4752-9fe6-e03658654836/excel-project-explorer-duplicate-sheet-entries?forum=exceldev

Comment: using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop; delete this and try again

Comment: Hi All,
Thank for the inputs.
It looks like that article is exactly what I am seeing in the excel file.
But seems no solution for this issue.

1. Creating new sheets and save the file again does not make those duplicate ones gone.
2. It is still the same after removing using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;